# bot telegram with php(relation of sendmessage and get message from user)

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

in telegram bot (php)
how can identify relation between message that send to user and user write answer ?
how can I identify if it is the answer of this text in telegram bot
code like this
first I put 5 button and when user press each button user must enter the text 
i want identify it is the answer of specific button.
how can I identify this with php?

Answer (score 4):

1. When user select one question from bot menu , store it in database. for example user select 'question2':

   ```
   storLastPlace($userId,'question2');
   ```
2. When comes new message to bot from this user , check it last place and do proper action ex:

   ```
   $lastPlace = getLastPlace($userId);
   if($lastPlace){
       switch ($lastPlace) {
       case 'question1':
           // recive answer1
           break;
       case 'question2':
           // recive answer1
           break;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks this is a good solution for web services but we can use dictionary in c sharp and then if program crashed and not saved in database when program is restart return back and repeat and rescan last unwanted request again that one time is replied. your solution is better but when we have so many request we have heavy load on database server...

Comment: @saber-tabatabaee-yazdi the question is about php and php doesn't have dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, 
you can make a table/collection in your Database and save the last sent message with Telegram ID of the user, it can be like this:

```
{
    userID : xxxxxx
    lastMessageSent : Button1
}
```